# Volume fluctuations on iOS Safari (iPad)

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I am playing mp4 files using SoundManager 2. This works as expected in desktop Chrome, desktop Safari, and desktop Firefox. However, in iPad Safari each mp4 plays at a different volume. Specifically, the first few play very very quietly, but every now and then one of them plays at full volume. I am explicitly setting the volume attribute, but this does not help, and does not seem to change anything regardless what value I set it to.

I am experiencing something very similar with an HTML video tag I am also using. The volume is normal everywhere else, but on iPad safari, about half of the time the playback is super quiet.

Comment: Same on iOS 13 (iPhone). Have you found out what was the cause?

Comment: This is audio stream from my mp4: `Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 72 kb/s (default)`. Possibly that's the reason for those squeaky sounds.

Comment: Thanks @Igniter, no I haven't found the issue yet, but I suspect it may be related to the fact that I have an audio media stream going at the same time. Have you found any clues?

Comment: I'm also experiencing strange behaviours in iOS Safari audio playback. Sometimes it starts with very low volume, and if I click the address bar of Safari, the volume will be much louder, so strange.